# Angular Universal APP & Lumen API, local development HttpErrorResponse (Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error)

Tags: javascript, angular, networking, lumen, angular-universal

I have Angular application with SSR (Angular Universal) + API (Laravel/Lumen).

After building the client and server app, i serve the application on http://localhost:9000

And serve the API on http://localhost:8000

The problem appears when application tries to make a request (while ssr) but there is no problem after the application is loaded on the client (browser), same request goes trough.

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: HttpHeaders { normalizedNames: Map {}, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map {} },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: null,
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error',
  error:
   ProgressEvent {
     type: 'error',
     target:
      XMLHttpRequest {...
```

I know its not a CORS issue since i have to following headers set in the API:

```
$headers = [
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age' => '86400',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
];
```

When i upload the application and the API on server, everything works fine.

There is no way to test the application localy (if the SSR was done alright).

So i'm guessing it is some networking issue, maybe the scope, the application can't see the API?!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Omar nope, i didn't :(

Comment: @Omar as it turns out you need to allow nodejs to communcate through Windows Defender Firewall (Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall\Allowed apps - on Windows 10)